# Linux top command hang about 25 seconds before works fine

Tags: linux, command-line, top, strace

On my Linux server, `top` command hang about 25 seconds before works fine:

```
$ time top -b -n 1
```

**Output:**

```
...
real    0m25.199s
user    0m0.018s
sys     0m0.014s
```

When `top` command is hang, I found the broken symlink in `/proc/`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$(pgrep top)/fd/
```

[image]

After `top` command works fine, there is no broken symlink in `/proc`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$(pgrep top)/fd/
```

[image]

I'm use `strace  top` to troubleshot the problem, and found the `EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)` message in the output:
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310) For the record, the other copy is on SU: [here](https://superuser.com/q/1638115/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski [cross-posting is off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073/286107) for [unix.SE]